# Suppose that $p$ is a prime number and $q\mid p−1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Suppose that $p$ is  a  prime  number  and $q\mid p−1$.   Prove  that  the  congruence $$1 +x+···+x^{q−1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$ has exactly $q−1$ solutions.

Now I know how to prove there are at most $q-1$ solutions, but I do not know how to prove there cannot be less than $q-1$ solutions.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

The solutions of the congruence are precisely the solutions to $x^q - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ such that $x\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Since $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field, this congruence has at most $q-1$ solutions.

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{\ast}$ be a primitive root -- then $\alpha^{(p-1)/q}$ has order $q$, so every $\alpha^{k(p-1)/q}$ for $1\le k \le q-1$ is a solution to the congruence. Hence the congruence has at least $q-1$ solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am confused why the order of $\alpha^{(p-1)/q}$ is q? Do you mean q times q is p-1?